# What's does it mean of" /* overloaded elements data types */ #define OE_IS_ARRAY (1<<0) #define OE_IS_OBJECT (1<<1) #define OE_IS_METHOD (1<<2)"?

Tags: php, c

Today,when I read php kernel codes, which in dir: `php5.3/Zend/Zend.h`, there was a line code make me confused.

Code is follow:

```
/* overloaded elements data types */
#define OE_IS_ARRAY     (1<<0)
#define OE_IS_OBJECT    (1<<1)
#define OE_IS_METHOD    (1<<2)
```

Is it means like this? And I use int type which has four bytes,it shows left shift operations.

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 = 0
After 1 <<
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 = 0
___________________________________________

0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 = 1
After 1<<
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 = 2
___________________________________________

0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 = 1
After 1<<
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 = 4
```

But if she/he want do this why not just assign the const variables directly?

```
/* overloaded elements data types */
#define OE_IS_ARRAY     (0)//turn the 1<<0 directly
#define OE_IS_OBJECT    (2)//turn the 1<<1 directly
#define OE_IS_METHOD    (4)//turn the 1<<2 directly
```

If you know please help me ,thanks a lot! :)

Comment: It is just to visualize that it is a bitmask.

Comment: I just edited to fix your bit tables.  Take a look.  1<<0 is a 1, not a 0.  Shifting the any value by 0 bits leaves it alone. Also, those shift amounts are also bit numbers (on a machine that numbers from the low bit, anyway) so that this can also match up the constant with external documentation.  This happens more with hardware and definitions of bits in a port by bit number.

Comment: @MikeHousky I'm sorry,I don't understand what you said,can you make it more clearly with code example,thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is usually used to make it unambiguous that you're talking about bit flags.  1, 2, and 4 will make most programmers realize that we're talking about a sequence of powers of 2; not everyone will instantly know that 1<<14 is 16384.  The compiler will do these computations for you, so it will not slow the program down.  It's all about clarity.

You'll sometimes also see these things written in hexadecimal, because that maps more closely to the underlying binary representation than decimal constants and can be more compact.